# Is there a way to change from V3 to V2 ReCAPTCHA?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am using Ontraport forms and they can only take V2 ReCAPTCHA and no matter where I go I cannot escape V3 ReCAPTCHA. Even when setting up a new key I only get the V3 option :(

Comment: why do you want to switch to an old version?

Comment: Because Ontraport can't work with V3